# Words in a range (lists) [Python]

Tags: python, list, file

I need help with this assignment because I'm extremely stuck (even my tutor bailed on me). I'm fairly new to python, so please don't be too brutal on me. Any help will be amazing. I'll list off everything the problem gives me...

"Write a program that first reads in the name of an input file, followed by two strings representing the lower and upper bounds of a search range. The file should be read using the file.readlines() method. The input file contains a list of alphabetical, ten-letter strings, each on a separate line. Your program should output all strings from the list that are within that range (inclusive of the bounds)."

Ex: If the input is:

```
input1.txt
ammoniated
millennium
```

and the contents of input1.txt are:

```
aspiration
classified
federation
graduation
millennium
philosophy
quadratics
transcript
wilderness
zoologists
```

the output is:

```
aspiration
classified
federation
graduation
millennium
```

Notes:

There is a newline at the end of the output.
input1.txt is available to download.
In the tests, the first word input always comes alphabetically before the second word input.

Thank you for any help! - :)

Edit - My current code:

```
user = open(input())
sequence1 = input()
sequence2 = input()

lines = user.readlines()

for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
    if sequence1 <= line <= sequence2:
        print(line)
```

Final edit - I appreciate everyone answering and providing explanations! The whole idea of files really confused me when it was introduced so seeing different ways of tackling this code helped me immensely. I'm using this experience to learn and I'm sorry for any confusion that I caused along the way. I also apologize because I'm very new on this site and I didn't realize how to do somethings on this website either because I panic made this post because as I mentioned, my tutor bailed on me and didn't give me a second resort. Thank you all!

Comment: "stuck" implies that you've at  least tried some things.  Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: update the question with the code, not the comments!

Comment: No one can help if you don't post your code

Comment: Oops. Sorry. I'm still new to using this website.

Comment: Are you sure that is the right code?  The question doesn't say anything about accumulating a total.

Comment: Since I'm fairly new, I try a bunch of different things and learn along the way. I'm not very used to coding yet, so I searched for help on solving this question and this is what got me closest. Half of the code didn't make any sense to me though, so I understand the confusion.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't seem related to the assignment at all, except that it reads from a file.

Answer (score 2):

updating w/ context...

Given the following as `x.txt`

```
aspiration
classified
federation
graduation
millennium
philosophy
quadratics
transcript
wilderness
zoologists
```

Here is the code you're looking for...

```
lower = "ammoniated"
upper = "millennium"
filename = "x.txt"

def wordKey(x: str) -> bool:
    return lower <= x <= upper

with open(filename, "r") as f:
    words = list(filter(wordKey, [word.strip() for word in f.readlines()]))
    f.close()
```

```
['aspiration', 'classified', 'federation', 'graduation', 'millennium']
```

**compact:**

```
lower = "ammoniated"
upper = "millennium"
filename = "x.txt"    

print(list(filter(lambda x: lower <= x <= upper, [word.strip() for word in open(filename, "r").readlines()])))
```

add some input to those variables:

```
lower = input("input lower bound: ")
upper = input("input upper bound: ")
filename = input("Enter filename (example: text.txt): ")
```

[image: output]

Comment: I really appreciate the in-depth explanation. Again, I'm fairly new to Python and I'm even newer on this site, so I really do appreciate it. I'm not very great at coding, so this class is kicking me pretty hard (Hopefully I'll improve). Thank you!

Comment: No problem, if you need more explanation feel free to contact me/ask here! Happy coding and good luck with python

Answer (score 1):

It's easier if you follow the prompt and use `readlines` which returns a list. Get the index of the first word, and of the last word; slice between the two (+1 the last word index for inclusivity). Use `rstrip` to get rid of the new line escaped character. `input()` takes an optional parameter to prompt the user for what they want to run this against. If you need the total of lines output, like in your original code (but not in the prompt you posted?), just call `len(someList)` again over the final slice, or just get the difference of `lastIdx - firstIdx`

```
file = input("file name: ")
firstWord = input("first word: ")
lastWord = input("last word: ")
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
firstIdx = 0
lastIdx = len(lines)
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line == firstWord:
        firstIdx = i
    if line == lastWord:
        lastIdx = i

print(lines[firstIdx:lastIdx+1])
```

Comment: Yeah, the assignments on these sites are really weirdly worded and sometimes expect you to output things that weren't mentioned until you repeatedly test it. I found that a lot of people in my class had the same problem and I do believe it's the site's fault. I really do appreciate your help in helping me solve this! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

***Fellow student here using the zyBooks material!

The trick to this problem is accounting for the fact that the lower and/or upper inputs may not actually be a line in the file,but rather solely just a point to start alphabetically.
It also accounts for multiple lines of the file beginning and/or ending with the same first index and did not necessarily come first alphabetically.. ( eg. if "lower" was "Houston", but the file included "Harrisburg, Houston, Huntsville"

This codeblock will open the file, then loop through each line of the file and print each line whose entire range of letters alphabetically fall between the lower and upper ranges. without the index range of [0:9], *"if lower[0:9] <= i[0:9] <= upper[0:9]:"*, the program wont account for the above.

```
userInput = input()

lower = input()
upper = input()
    

with open(userInput, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines() 
    for i in lines:
        if lower[0:9] <= i[0:9] <= upper[0:9]:
            print(i.strip())
```

Comment: Hey, I apologize for the late response, but I still appreciate the help! I solved this issue a long while back and have come a long way from those days in Zybooks. Still learning to code but with much more experience! I find making this post useful for anybody else learning and wanting to improve their coding skills when they're unsure of somethings in python! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```py
filename = input() # 'input1.txt'
start = input() # 'ammoniated'
end = input() # 'millennium'

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    words = f.readlines()
for w in words:
    if w < start or end < w:
        continue
    print(w)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I tried them all to see what different outputs it gave me, so I do appreciate it. Thanks!